# how to use g2o?

Tags: ros, slam, g2o, ros-kinetic, graph

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can you give some information about how to use g2o?Do i have to use it with a ros distribution? is there any advantage to use them together?if yes,how can i interoperate them?

thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256267/how-to-use-g2o?/) by [ali ekber celik](https://answers.ros.org/users/8866/ali-ekber-celik/) on ROS Answers with karma: 114 on 2017-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What exactly do you mean? G2O is a C++-library for graph optimization and is not connected with ROS directly.

It looks like the g2o version that comes with ROS cannot be used, because it is not found by catkin. So the only way I see at the moment is to download the source from g2o, install it with "make install" and then find it using the FindG2O.cmake provided by g2o itself.

I already opened an issue regarding this: https://github.com/RainerKuemmerle/g2o/issues/156

---

Originally posted by [Sebastian Kasperski](https://answers.ros.org/users/1640/sebastian-kasperski/) with karma: 1658 on 2017-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1